# Checking parent checkbox doesn't check child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to get some jquery to check the child checkbox when the parent is selected, however it is not happening and I can't for the life of me figure out what the deal is.

Code:

```
$('#check-all-parent').click(function(event) {
if(this.checked) { // check select status
    $('#check-all-child').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
        this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
    });
}else{
    $('#check-all-child').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
        this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
    });         
}  
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check-all-parent">hello
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check-all-child">hello2
```

Here is the [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/evx9y8g9/)

Comment: Probably because ID's **must** be unique - so running an each loop on an ID selector doesnt make much sense.

Comment: I wish that were the case, even changing them to a class doesn't do it.

Comment: Ehh - yes it does: http://jsfiddle.net/evx9y8g9/1/

Comment: I have updated everything to reflect your suggestion see  [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/evx9y8g9/) however is there a way to make it so that if you select the child the parent gets selected also?

Comment: @zemaker, you were fine from the beginning. You just need to add jQuery as a library in jsfiddle. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class instead of id.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check-all-parent">hello
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check-all-child">hello2
```

jQuery

```
$('#check-all-parent').click(function(event) {
if(this.checked) { // check select status
    $('.check-all-child').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
        this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
    });
}else{
    $('.check-all-child').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
        this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
    });         
}
```

Comment: This resolved it, here is the updated [fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/evx9y8g9/8/) with the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, you just need to add jQuery in the jsfiddle. Click the first drop-down under Frameworks & Extensions, and choose a jQuery library (like this: [jsfiddle.net/evx9y8g9/3](http://jsfiddle.net/evx9y8g9/3)).

Your JS could be a bit cleaner though:

```
$('#check-all-parent').click(function() {
    $("#check-all-child").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `loop`. Use `class` instead of `id` and in js:

```js
$(".check-all-parent").on("click", function() {
  $(".check-all-child").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check-all-parent">hello
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check-all-child">hello2
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check-all-child">hello2
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check-all-child">hello2
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check-all-child">hello2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have parent an child checkboxes, consider using a nested list:

```html
<ul id="checkboxes">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox"> hello
    <ul>
      <li> <input type="checkbox"> hello1 </li>
      <li> <input type="checkbox"> hello2 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then use

```js
$('#checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this)
  .nextAll('ul')
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```js
$('#checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this)
  .nextAll('ul')
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="checkboxes">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    hello
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        hello1
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox">
            hello11
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        hello2
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        hello3
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```